# Declaring <?php ?> in variables

Tags: custom-field, menus, comments, admin-menu, variables

I need to put the PHP `<?php global $' . $icon_var . '; echo $' . $icon_var . '; ?>` inside the variable of a custom menu structure, but it gets commented:

```
<a href="http://slembas.esy.es/">
    <!--?php global $icon_home; echo $icon_home; ?-->
    <span>Page Name</span>
</a>
```

Explanation of the variables:

`$icon_var` - gets value from a custom input `_menu_custom_item` where I write variable without `$` which contain SVG code to make menu items fancier with icons.

```
 function sidebar_menu() {
    $menu_name = 'sidebar_pages';
    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
        $menu       = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
        $menu_list  = '<nav>' . "\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t" . '<ul>' . "\n";
        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
            $icon_var = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_custom', true );
            $title    = $menu_item->title;
            $url      = $menu_item->url;
            $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t" . '<li><a href="' . $url . '"><?php global $' . $icon_var . '; echo $' . $icon_var . '; ?><span>' . $title . '</span></a></li>' . "\n";
        }

        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t" . '</ul>' . "\n";
        $menu_list .= "\t\t\t" . '</nav>' . "\n";
    }
    else {
        // $menu_list = '<!-- no list defined -->';

    }

    echo $menu_list;
}
```

The desired output should look like:

```
<li>
    <a href="/" class="icon" title="Главная">
        <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="#000000" d="M10,20V14H14V20H19V12H22L12,3L2,12H5V20H10Z"></path>
        </svg>
        <span>Главная‌​</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please ask future PHP questions on StackOverflow instead. This is where it fits better and where you will get more answers (and not a closed question). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `global $variable;` before you can use the variable. Try the code below instead for that line.

```
// setup your global scope here

global $icon_var;

// set the new value in global scope

$icon_var = get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_custom', true);  

// then use the variable

$menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t<li><a href=\"$url\">$icon_var<span>$title</span></a></li>\n";
```

---

### DYNAMIC GLOBAL VARIABLE NAME

If you Created your data in a [global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) variable and now you want to access it with a dynamic name reference then use the [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) directly.

```
// 'icon_home' set as global

global $icon_home;
$icon_home = '<svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> <path fill="#000000" d="M10,20V14H14V20H19V12H22L12,3L2,12H5V20H10Z"></path></svg>';

// variable name retrieved dynamically

// 'icon_home';
$icon_var = get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_custom', true); 
$icon = $GLOBALS [$icon_var]; 

// output icon

echo "\t\t\t\t\t<li><a href=\"$url\">$icon<span>$title</span></a></li>\n";
```

Comment: It just echoes the `_menu_custom_item` value instead of `<?php global $icon_home; echo $icon_home; ?>`. Like this: `<a href="http://slembas.esy.es/">
$icon_home
<span>Главная</span>
</a>`

Comment: Yes, It need to be executed.

Comment: Am I stupid or what... (I am stupid at PHP). Still doesn't work. Just shows the variable. To make it clear, that's how the compiled code should look: `<li><a href="/" class="icon" title="Главная">
      <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">    <path fill="#000000" d="M10,20V14H14V20H19V12H22L12,3L2,12H5V20H10Z"></path></svg>      <span>Главная</span>
     </a></li>`

Comment: And the only problem was commented `<!--?php global $icon_home; echo $icon_home; ?-->`. It just should be uncommented.

Comment: Oh my! After experimenting with changing the code by your samples I finally got it to work! `$icon = $GLOBALS [$icon_var];` helped. Thank you really much!

Comment: Cool. In the future always put down your desired result in the question and any values that are coming out of your metadata. Otherwise it's just a guessing game on possible solutions. Best,

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. Im very grateful to [jgraup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/84219/jgraup)!

All that I needed to change is to add `$icon = $GLOBALS[$icon_var];` and change the `$menu_list` structure as jgraup recommended. Even there is no need for third-party changes.

The final code:

```
function sidebar_menu()
{
$menu_name = 'sidebar_pages';
if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name]))
    {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
    $menu_list = '<nav>' . "\n";
    $menu_list.= "\t\t\t\t" . '<ul>' . "\n";
    foreach((array)$menu_items as $key => $menu_item)
        {
        $icon_var = get_post_meta($menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_custom', true);
        $icon = $GLOBALS[$icon_var];
        $title = $menu_item->title;
        $url = $menu_item->url;
        $menu_list.= "\t\t\t\t\t<li><a class=\"icon\" href=\"$url\">$icon<span>$title</span></a></li>\n";
        }

    $menu_list.= "\t\t\t\t" . '</ul>' . "\n";
    $menu_list.= "\t\t\t" . '</nav>' . "\n";
    }
  else
    {

    // $menu_list = '<!-- no list defined -->';

    }

echo $menu_list;
}
```